# How to get a count of records in MongoDB using a Lookup as a Reference

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a polling system. I have a collection of choices and a collection of votes

Choices collection, showing the choices available in 'poll1'

```
_id:'1',
pollId:'poll1',
choice:'red'

_id:'2',
pollId:'poll1',
choice:'blue'

_id:'3',
pollId:'poll1'
choice:'green'
```

Votes collection

```
_id:'a'
choiceId:'3'  // corresponds to the _id in the Choices collection
userId:'user1'  // id of the user who voted 

_id:'b'
choiceId:'3'
userId:'user2'

_id:'c'
choiceId:'1'
userId:'user3'
```

I would like to be able to count the number of votes for each choice in a poll. At the moment I have the following basic query on the Votes collection which returns just the id of the choice and the number of votes

```
[
    {
        '$match': {
            'pollId': pollId
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
             '_id': '$choiceId', 
             'votes': {
                 '$sum': 1
             }
         }
    }
]
```

However, I would like to be able to use a lookup on the Choices collection as a reference - for every available choice in a poll, get the choiceId, the choiceName, and a count of the number of votes for that choice.

From reading the docs it would seems to be something like this, but it just returns an array of all the choices for that poll, and a total count of the votes, not the votes for each choice

```
[
   {
       '$match': {
           'pollId': pollId
       }
   }, {
       '$lookup': {
            'from': 'choices', 
            'localField': 'pollId', 
            'foreignField': 'pollId', 
            'as': 'choiceData'
        }
   }, {
       '$group': {
           '_id': '$choiceData._id', 
           'votes': {
               '$sum': 1
           }
       }
    }
 ]
```

Could anyone please explain how to get data in the following sort of structure:

```
choiceId:'3', choice:'green', votes:2

choiceId:'1', choice:'red', votes:1

choiceId:'2', choice:'blue', votes:0
```

Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$match` by your poll name (as you do).
- Then use `$lookup` to merge collections. But here there are a few thing to do better: `from` is the other collection, `localField` is the field from the collection who is doing the lookup and `foreignField` is the other collection. So you have to join with `votes` collection where the field `_id` in `choices` collection is the same as `choiceId` in `votes` collection.
- And last `$project` to get the values you want. In this case set `choiceId` as the `_id` and `votes` as the number of results returned by lookup (i.e. the number of votes).

```
db.choices.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "pollId": "poll1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "votes",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "choiceId",
      "as": "choiceData"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "choice": 1,
      "choiceId": "$_id",
      "votes": {
        "$size": "$choiceData"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3sZNOiF42UE)

Comment: That's fantastic J.F., many thanks. Of course, for some reason I'd used the votes collection as my starting point and trying to reference back, instead of using the choices as the starting point and then counting the votes. Really well explained - thanks again